# Change label position of Doughnut Chart from PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs, primereact

I am new to React and would like to change the position of the labels for the Doughnut chart from PrimeReact(https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/doughnutchart).

I checked the link(https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html) which primereact internally used for chart and find no option to change position etc. Is there a way to achieve?

I also would like to have some text at the center of the doughnut.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Chart jsx:

```
const option = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: false,
  legend: {
  position: 'left',
  labels: {
  boxWidth: 10
  }
 }
}
```

### Apply above option to Chart

```
<Chart
   style={{ width: "90%", height: "90%" }}
   type="doughnut"
   data={data}
   options={option}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from user578219 was perfect for my problem as well.  I am also looking for the option to include a label in the center of the doughnut - is there anywhere that I can find a list of the options that can be used?